# Are XML and JSON the data format standards in the food and beverage industry?

Tags: json, xml, format, standards

I'm working on a nutrition smart phone application, and I want to know what data formats are industry standards within the food and beverage industry.

Comment: Perhaps https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/269/open-api-for-nutritional-information-and-or-food-barcodes is helpful. And the opendata forum seems a better bet for this kind of question than a programming forum.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Answer (score -2):

I've found this paper on XML standard (attempt) for Industry. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/200594256_Organization_of_Batch_Process_Using_XML_Schema. Nothing seems perfectly clear from UNSPSC, GS1 or ARTS. What kind of standard are you looking for ?

Comment: so, it seems not to be a good answer. Even if this is a real answer which tells there is non document available.